# Why does this PHP snippet behave this way?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm just doing some recursion exercises in PHP and I'm a bit baffled by the output of the following:

```
function calc($numTimes, $i, $total) {
    if (!$i && !$total) {$i = 1; $total = 1;}
    if ($i <= $numTimes) {
        $total = $total*2;
        $i++;
        calc($numTimes, $i, $total);
    }
    echo $total.'+'.$i.'<br />';
}
calc(5);
```

Before running it I would've assumed the output to be ***32+6***.  However, this is what I get:

```
32+6
32+6
16+5
8+4
4+3
2+2
```

I don't get it.  The output is not only 5 lines longer than I would've expected it to be, but instead of incrementing the total, it's removing from it?  Also, if I add a break; after the echo, it only returns ***32+6***, which somehow seems relevant.  However, when I change the code so that it uses return $total; instead of echo:

```
function calc($numTimes, $i, $total) {
    if (!$i && !$total) {$i = 1; $total = 1;}
    if ($i <= $numTimes) {
        $total = $total*2;
        $i++;
        calc($numTimes, $i, $total);
    }
    return $total.'+'.$i.'<br />';
}
$r = calc(5);
echo $r;
```

This is what gets printed out:

```
2+2
```

I'm a bit confused and hoping someone can help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: what is `$sum` ? what are you trying to do? how should I figure that out if your code is broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not doing anything with the recursive call.
the line:

```
calc($numTimes, $i, $total);
```

might calculcate a value, but does nothing with it. notice that the returned value is never saved. you would have to fetch it:

```
$res = calc($numTimes, $i, $total);
```

and then keep going with $res

i think what you meant is:

```
function calc($numTimes, $i = 0, $total = 0) {
    if (!$i && !$total) {$i = 1; $total = 1;}
    if ($i <= $numTimes) {
        $total = $total*2;
        $i++;
        return calc($numTimes, $i, $total);
    }
    return $total.'+'.$i.'<br />';
}
echo calc(5);
```

Comment: This works and returns only the value I'm interested in.  I'm quite interested to know why the total kept decreasing though.  Thank you for the tip on defining default values as well :)

Comment: when you are sending $total to the call, you are not sending the variable, but the value of the variable. any changes you make to $total will not affect the outer scopes. a new "$total" will be created for each recursive call

Comment: I get it now why it's decreasing... Each time it calls itself, it waits for the function call to finish, and spits out the current total of each function call as it finishes back up the tree... Lol :D  That was really my main interest to begin with :)  Thank you for the answer, it helped me realize what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `calc()` is called inside itself conditionally, hence it's looping and outputting numerous results (5 calls to echo).

In your second example, you have set a variable to be the result of the return value of `calc()`. It is still looping, but the result is overridden each time. So you have one result showing (echo is called once).

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo, using `$sum` instead of `$total` in the first `if` clause.